# Create array from PHP string

Tags: php, arrays, string

Let's say I have an string like

```
$str = "BKL|bkl,EXH|exh,FFV|ffv,LEC|lec,AUE|aue,SEM|SEM";
```

and i want an array like:

```
array( array("title"=>"BKL", "value"=>bkl),
array("title"=>"EXH", "value"=>exh),
array("title"=>"FFV", "value"=>ffv),
array("title"=>"LEC", "value"=>lec),
array("title"=>"AUE", "value"=>aue),
array("title"=>"SEM", "value"=>SEM),
);
```

I have found a solution here: [How to create particular array from string in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14209362/how-to-create-particular-array-from-string-in-php) but this is giving me an array like:

```
Array
(
    [BKL] => bkl
    [EXH] => exh
    [FFV] => ffv
    [LEC] => lec
    [AUE] => aue
    [SEM] => sem
)
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Use Your String which you want to display in foreach with `key` and `values`:**

Demo: https://eval.in/827426

```
<?php

$str = "BKL|bkl,EXH|exh,FFV|ffv,LEC|lec,AUE|aue,SEM|sem";

$final = array();

foreach (explode(',', $str) as $pair) {
  list($key, $value) = explode('|', $pair);
  $final[] = ['Title'=>$key .',', 'Value'=>$value];
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($final);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, i guess however a comma is missing after each inner array?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, but i meant a comma after the ) from the inner array, like
[0] => Array
        (
            [Title] => BKL
            [Value] => bkl
        ),

Comment: @RobbTe ... Here if you try Your self then it easy, then you can easily understand whats going on here ,

Comment: Hi, thanks..  i did find how to put an extra comma within the array, but i am not sure how to put a comma after the ) from the inner array.  So like (see the last comma)

`[0] => Array ( [Title] => BKL [Value] => bkl ),`

Comment: in the end of aaray you get the comma ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148337/discussion-between-rishikesh-kumar-and-robbte).

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is change the way the array is built up...

```
$str = "BKL|bkl,EXH|exh,FFV|ffv,LEC|lec,AUE|aue,SEM|sem";

$final = array();

foreach (explode(',', $str) as $pair) {
  list($key, $value) = explode('|', $pair);
  $final[] = ['title'=>$key, 'value'=>$value];
}

print_r($final);
```

Comment: Awesome thanks, i just wasn't sure about how the array was built in the first place. Most of the time more easy than you think:) thanks

Comment: Works, but shouldn't there be a comma after each "inner" array?